# Embed swf file in html

Tags: html, apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Embeded html file doesnt run on ubuntu system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798220/why-embeded-html-file-doesnt-run-on-ubuntu-system)

Hi guys, I am trying to embed swf file into html file but this is works in windows and mac browsers exactly. When I am trying in ubuntu ... it wont works.....

Why????

Comment: Add details to the original question instead of posting a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the plugin based on your OS/browser - http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/